# stacked canvas hided when validating

Tags: oracle, forms

i have stacked canvas A on tab canvas B when i entered a char in number item on canvas B it shows error which is ok but my stacked canvas B hided ! it is hided while validating any item on canvas B  .
how to solve this ?

thanks

Comment: Please review [ask]. Using that as a template for your question greatly increases your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. In this case please post table DDL, sad sample input data  as text **not images** and what result you expect. Finally, I figure English is not your native language, normally I can figure out from context, but I  am sorry, I just cannot figure what you mean by "hided". Can you describe what you mean?

Comment: thank you  i mean canvas A is hidden when validate any item on tab canvas B

Comment: Well thanks for responding. Unfortunately that seems to be strictly a Forms issue and not SQL. I hope you get an answer, but I cannot provide it - I no nothing about the workings of Oracle Forms.